# SwiftUi: How to reduce space between frame and Text?

Tags: ios, stack, swiftui, frame

I've tried to create a View for iOS in `SwiftUI` with rectangles as frames around Stacks but I can't reduce the space between a `Text` and a frame of `HStack`.

So in detail: I use a `VStack` with multiple `HStacks` inside. The problem occurs when I try to reduce the space between 2 `HStacks`.

In the following code snippet the first `Text` "Title" is inside an `HStack` with a `Spacer` followed by another `HStack` with 2 `Text` elements inside.

I want to have the first `Text` "Title" directly above the rectangle. No big space like I currently have.

Any suggestions?
Thank you very much.

Code:

```
var body: some View {   

     VStack() {
         HStack() {
             Text("Title")
                 .font(Font.body)
                 .cornerRadius(ViewConstants.CORNERRADIUS)
                 .padding()
                 .foregroundColor(Colours.BLUE)
             Spacer()
         } 
         HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
             Spacer()
             Text("SomeTextText")
                 .font(Font.bold(.body)())
                 .cornerRadius(ViewConstants.CORNERRADIUS)
                 .padding()
                 .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                 .clipped()
             Text("xx,00")
                 .font(Font.body)
                 .cornerRadius(ViewConstants.CORNERRADIUS)
                 .padding()
                 .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
             Spacer()
         } // HStack
             .overlay(
                 RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: ViewConstants.CORNERRADIUS)
                     .stroke(Colours.BLUE, lineWidth: 1)
                 )   .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 3, bottom: 0, trailing: 3))
...
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot as well?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have the first text "Title" directly above the rectangle. No
>   big space like I currently have.

I assume it is expected

[image]

```
Text("Title")
    .font(Font.body)
    .cornerRadius(ViewConstants.CORNERRADIUS)
    .padding(.horizontal) // << only horizontal padding
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems that I was blind on both eyes :D.
Thanks a lot.